# Does JScript Provide a Ternary Operator?

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

Do we have a ternary operator in Jscript (as opposed to JavaScript)? If so, what is the syntax?

Comment: Please note: Java, JScript and JavaScript are separate languages.

Comment: @Incognito given that JScript and JavaScript are separate languages, why changing the title?

Answer (score 5):

It's

```
expression ? expression : expression
```

just like C. It's a little looser, actually, because JavaScript is not strongly-typed. Thus the two possible "forks" of the operator can result in different types of values.

Thus:

```
alert(document.all ? "Hello from IE!" : "Hello from a non-IE browser!");
```

Most of the time, the differences between Microsoft's ECMAScript and those found in other browsers (or other server-side environments) aren't really that great, and for ordinary non-DOM code it's pretty rare to have to deal with such things.

Answer (score 2):

[yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zakwfxx4%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) it does.

```
test ? expression1 : expression2
```

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
var result = 5 > 10 ? '5 is greater than 10' : '5 is not greater than 10';
```

Comment: For clarity sake, and to insure proper precedence of operators, and to make this ultimately readable I would restate the rhs as ((5 > 10) ? '5 is greater than 10' : '5 is not greater than 10')

Comment: Thanks ZeSimon.. My Bad.. I just made some syntactical errors in my code and keep wondering why ternary doesn't working

Answer (score 0):

You can always use google to find language syntax, too.

The first result I got was, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.  It has examples like

```
var greeting = "Good" + ((now.getHours() > 17) ? " evening." : " day.");
```